# pygame flapy bird random pipe generation

Tags: python, pygame

for a school project, I am making flappy bird and i am trying to make the pipes randomly generate once the pipe reaches a certain piot to get a new pipe.

```
top = [pipe(start, -550, False), pipe (start , 300, True )]
mid = [pipe(start , -400, False), pipe(start , 400, True)]
bod = [pipe(start, -300, False), pipe(start , 500, True)]
obsitcal = mid








def obsit(obsitcal):
    for pipe in obsitcal:
        if pipe.x <= 50:
            pipenum = random.randint(1, 3)
            if pipenum == 1:
                obsitcal.append([pipe(start, -550, False), pipe(start , 300, True )])
            elif pipenum == 2:
                obsitcal = mid
            elif pipenum == 3:
                obsitcal = bod
```

once the pipe reaches the point where a new pipe should be generated the game stops and the error:

```
 obsitcal.append([pipe(start, -550, False), pipe(start , 300, True )])

TypeError: 'pipe' object is not callable
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're reassigning `pipe` in the loop, shadowing your `def pipe():` (which isn't in the question, but we can see it's a function).

I'd recommend renaming that `pipe` function to something with a verb, e.g. `make_pipe()`.

Comment: ok i tried changing the pipe in the for loop to make_pipe but now it throws the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: @JacksonPike Show us your new code, including the `make_pipe` function.

Comment: i cant past the whole code in but here is a link two it.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60574168/python-flappy-bird-help-part-2)